# Save variable c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, variables, save

how can i save a variable in c# (.net), i need this to save the score!
And when i start the game again, the variable is the same as before.
[image: And here is the variable]
Please help me find a very simple way.
I tried to find something about that in the web but its way to coplycated for me.

```
int Wins;

//CODE for saving Variable

label5.Text = "Matches won:" + Wins;
```

Sorry for my Bad English

Thank you!

Comment: What you are looking for is basically "persistence" if I am not mistaken. There are various ways to achieve it. You could use User-Settings, Files (Text, CSV, JSON, XML, ... INI ), Databases (SQLite would be one easy, single-file local DB), Registry (-no, don't), ... Are you on .Net Framework or .Net Core?

Comment: i think im on .net core

Comment: We need to know what kind of app this is; an ASP.NET web app? A Winform desktop app? UWP? How do you “start the game again”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing I think you should do is to store your data in a file. I suggest considering JSON - it is very popular now.

You can work with the `System.Text.Json` namespace which is supported by Microsoft. You can find some example and useful guide in the [Mirosoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).

Or you can work with `Newtonsoft.JSON` package [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).

Comment: which more simpel?

Comment: @Mah_superman3 if you want more simple, you can use normal File (not JSON). Here is some information for you to find out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/read-write-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your using a Webbaplication but otherwise you can store it in a session using javascript.

```
var score = 1;

sessionStorage.setItem("Score", score);

var score = sessionStorage.getItem("Score");
```

Edit
If you can't use javascript you could always do it with a file reader instead. Just make sure the url is right.

```
  public class saving_to_file
    {

        public void setScore(string playerScore, string aiScore)
        {
            string score = playerScore + "-" + aiScore;
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\scoreKeeper.txt", score);
        }

        public string[] getScore()
        {
            string score = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\scoreKeeper.txt");
            //Helps to clear the file of scores.
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\scoreKeeper.txt", String.Empty);

          return score.Split('-');
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks but im using a c# .net application, but thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON files or Database. JSON might be simpler to use by importing Newtonsoft nuget package (Newtonsoft.JSON). But using database you can use/access the scores wherever you want with more control over it in future.

Link for Newtonsoft Package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/